# How to use solr custom FunctionQuery in query constraint?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have written custom function query and added compiled class and registry to solrconfig.xml.
I can use it in field list and it return expected value:

```
/serch/query/myindex/q=*:*&fl=myfunc(field,'paramValue')
```

But if I use my custom function in query constraint it doesn't work:

```
/serch/query/myindex/q=myfunc(field,'paramValue'):value
```

So, what is the correct way to use custom function in query constraint?

Comment: please show your exception from solr.log, code of your custom function is welcome + solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 0):

See "[Using Function Queries](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Using_FunctionQuery)" on the Wiki.

> - Invoke the FunctionQParserPlugin via LocalParams syntax, e.g. q={!func}log(foo)   * Alternatively: Set func as the default query
>     type, e.g. defType=func&q=log(foo)
> - Invoke the FunctionRangeQParserPlugin via LocalParams syntax in a filter query, e.g. fq={!frange l=0}sub(field1,field2)
> - Use a parameter that has an explicit type of FunctionQuery, such as DisMaxQParserPlugin's bf (boost function) parameter, or extended
>     dismax boost parameter (multiplicative boost).
> - Embed a FunctionQuery in a regular query expressed in SolrQuerySyntax via the _val_ hook

The second option will allow you to use the function in an `fq` (at least very straight forward if your function returns a numeric value).

Comment: Thans, it works. How can I use function dereference to don't repet invoke function: q=*:*&fq={!frange l=0}myfunc(field)&fl=myfunc(field)&sort=myfunc(field)+asc. This dosn't work for me: q=*:*&myfuncFunc=myfunc(field)&fl=$myfuncFunc&sort=$myfuncFunc+asc